# Salida inesperada al remplazar palabras duplicadas en una cadena

Tags: java

Tengo una clase con un `main` en la que tengo declarado cinco variables y he de introducir por teclado una cadena.

Consiste en ver si se repite una palabra y en ese caso eliminarla, indicar cuantas veces se repite las palabras duplicadas y las que no.

Es decir, si mi cadena es `"Hola que tal Hola"` la salida esperada seria `"Hola : 2 , que : 1 , tal : 1 "` y `"Hola que tal"`.

Para ello he realizado un `for` que recorre la longitud de la cadena y dentro hay una variable de tipo `String` que almacena los caracteres que va recorriendo, seguido tengo una condicion que compara si son iguales, si son iguales remplazo la palabra por un espacio en blanco.

Pero no me esta dando la salida esperada

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainII {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Dime una frase");
        String cadena = sc.nextLine(); // Palabra introducida por teclado

        int contador = 0; // Contador de palabras 

        String frase [] = cadena.split(" "); //En cada posicion esta una palabra
        String palabra = ""; // Almacena la palabra de manera temporal 

        for(int i=0; i<frase.length; i++) {

        palabra = palabra + cadena.charAt(i);   

        if(frase[i].equals(palabra)){

        contador++; 
        frase[i] = cadena.replaceAll(palabra, " ");



        }else {

        contador++;

        }

        palabra = "";

        System.out.print( frase[i] + " " + "Se repite : " + contador + " veces " + "\n");
        contador = 0;

        }



        System.out.println("\n" + "Tiene tantas palabras :" + frase.length);


        }
}
```

Comment: Hola Talbara. ¿Y qué salida te está dando con este código?

Comment: Si introduzco como cadena : "hola que tal hola" , la salida es ( hola Se repite : 1 veces, que Se repite : 2 veces, tal Se repite : 3 veces,  que tal   Se repite : 4 veces ,Tiene tantas palabras :4 )

Comment: el for lo haces iterando un arreglo es decir por cada palabra que contiene frase. Luego asignas a palabra el carácter (charAt(i) trae una sola letra) de string cadena. Siempre va  por else. Por otro lado le estas quitando a la cadena todas las ocurrencia de la palabra. El siguiente Hola no lo vas a encontrar porque se lo borraste de la cadena. ¿No sería más fácil tener otro array e ir poniendo las palabras en este? Si ya existe entonces acumulas algonpor el estilo.

Comment: Por favor, podrias explicar linea por linea que hace tu programa? Ahi te vas a dar cuenta de los errores que tenes (que son todos de la logica de tu programa)

Comment: Se me ocurre que cada palabra que leas de tu frase la guardes en un `HashMap`, comprobando previamente si ya tienes esa palabra en el `HashMap`. Si no existe, la creas y le das como `value` el valor `1` (una repetición de esa palabra de momento). Si ya existe, solo tienes que incrementar el `value` en `1`. Al terminar recorres el `HashMap` pidiendo cada `key` (palabras distintas en tu frase) y su `value` (repeticiones de esa palabra en tu frase).

Comment: A pesar de los consejos ofrecidos no he conseguido sacar la solución si alguien puede ofrecerme la solución actuando sobre mi código lo agradecería